# Peskin Schroeder $\phi^4$ mass renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, mass, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

In Peskin Schroeder, section 10.2, the contributions to $M^2(p^2)$ of order $\lambda^2$ are calculated. The respective Feynman diagrams are given:
[image]

why is this diagram NOT included?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just before their statement that the first non-zero corrections to the $\phi^4$-propagator are those you indicated, they compute the one-loop corrections, *using on-shell renormalization conditions*, and find out that they are zero:

[image: The one-loop result]

It seems that for the $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ (two-loop) corrections, one should indeed consider not only the diagram you pointed out but another one with a counterterm insertion, which cancels it due to the above one-loop result in the considered scheme. Schematically:

[image: The full two-loop sum]

Where the fourth diagram corresponds to the one you drew and the fifth term is the $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ contribution with the counterterm insertion.